# Long to Wide in Python Pandas Similar to IBM SPSS Data Restructure Cases into Variables

Tags: python, pandas, pivot

I have groups of related cases in a dataset that I want to rearrange so that data, which consists of numerical and non-numerical data, are represented as a single case in the resulting data frame. Essentially, I have multiple measurements of the same subject over time, thus there are duplicate ID numbers in my dataset. Additionally, there is no need to aggregate the restructured data.

In SPSS, I would use the following code [(link to SPSS function)](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSLVMB_27.0.0/statistics_reference_project_ddita/spss/base/syn_casestovars_overview.html):

```
CASESTOVARS  
  /ID=PropertyLocation
  /GROUPBY=INDEX.
```

The result would look similar to the image below in which the variables associated with each case have been added as new variables with a count included in the variable name (example 'date' variable for case 1 is 'date'. 'date.1' is used for second observation performed at a later time of case 1).

[image]

In Python, I've tried using df.pivot_table, but it is aggregating my numerical values and not displaying my non-numerical data.

[image]

My code in Python is as follows:

```
reshaped_sales = sales_data_cleansed_2.pivot_table(index="Property Location", columns="sales_index")
```

Column 'sales_index' is simply a count of each repeated measure of each case. Not all cases are repeatedly measured the same number of times.

Here is the sample dataset https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Q56bVaLCxfY5jF1C0vhVEmpMtyq7dQif/view?usp=sharing

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: no sample data - looks like a standard use of `stack()`

Comment: Hi Rob - I've added the raw sample data.

Comment: In your description there are columns that don't exist.  `df.set_index("Property Location").T` will transform from long to wide

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of searching and testing, this is a solution that works for a minimal DataFrame. You should be able to apply the concepts to your large DataFrame, if you're still needing this answer!

```
### Python code to mimic SPSS's "CASESTOVARS /ID=ProjectID /GROUPBY=INDEX."
import pandas as pd

### Long DataFrame recording dates of changes to insurance:
df = pd.DataFrame({
    ### ID variables to group by:
    'ProjectID': pd.Series([11, 22, 33, 11, 22, 33, 33, 22, 33]).astype('string')
    ,'id_fam': pd.Series(['Blue', 'Green', 'Yellow','Blue', 'Green', 'Yellow', 'Yellow', 'Green', 'Yellow']).astype('string')
    ,'id_kid': pd.Series(['John', 'Jill', 'Jack', 'John', 'Jill', 'Jack', 'Jack', 'Jill', 'Jack']).astype('string')
    ### Variable that should always be the same for each grouping:
    ,'Funding': pd.Series(['Type1', 'Type1', 'Type2', 'Type1', 'Type1', 'Type2', 'Type2', 'Type1', 'Type2']).astype('string')
    ### Variables that change for each grouping:
    ,'InsStatus': pd.Series(['A', 'B', 'C', 'D','A', 'B', 'A', 'C', 'C']).astype('string')
    ,'InsDateChecked': pd.date_range('2018-01-01', periods=9, freq='d')
})

### Sorting by IDs and Date:
df = df.sort_values(by=['ProjectID', 'id_fam', 'id_kid', 'InsDateChecked'], na_position='first', ignore_index=True)

### Pivot the DataFrame:
df_pivoted = df.pivot_table(
    index=['ProjectID', 'id_fam', 'id_kid', 'Funding'] ### All columns that do not change (if not listed will be deleted).
    ,columns=df.groupby(['ProjectID', 'id_fam', 'id_kid']).cumcount() + 1 ### Cumulative count of rows within groupings so groups of data stack vertically. DF should be sorted beforehand. 
    ,values=['InsStatus', 'InsDateChecked'] ### Columns that change.
    ,aggfunc='first' ### To use the values themselves and not an aggregation.
)

### Reorder exploded columns (while all other columns still in the row index & while column names still a MultiIndex):
df_pivoted = df_pivoted.sort_index(axis=1, level=0, ascending=False).sort_index(axis=1, level=1, sort_remaining=False) 

### Flatten the column MultiIndex & rename columns in the style of SPSS:
df_pivoted.columns = [f'{col[0]}.{col[1]}' for col in df_pivoted.columns]

### Reset row & column indices:
df_pivoted = df_pivoted.reset_index()

print(df)
print('\n')
print(df_pivoted)
```